# Convergence of Sequence with a Recursive Bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Claim.** Given a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $p_n \to p$ and a constant $0 \leq k < 1$ such that $|p_n - p| \leq k |p_{n-1} - p|$ for every integer $n \geq 1,$ prove that for every integer $n \geq 1$ $$|p_n - p| \leq \frac{k}{1-k} |p_n - p_{n-1}|.$$

I have been thinking about this problem for the entire weekend, and I am still not sure how to approach it. Unfortunately, the Triangle Inequality does not seem to be very helpful. I would greatly appreciate any hints or tips that could be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$
|p_n - p| \leq k|p_{n-1}-p| \leq k|p_{n-1}-p_n| + k|p_n-p|
$$

we get

$$
(1-k)|p_n-p| \leq k|p_n - p_{n-1}|
$$

and dividing by $(1-k)$ which is positive,

$$
|p_n-p| \leq \frac{k}{1-k}|p_n-p_{n-1}|.
$$

Note that convergence is not necessary since it is a *consequence* of the former bound:

$$
|p_n -p| \leq k|p_{n-1}-p| \leq \dots \leq k^{n}|p_0-p| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
$$

Comment: I figured it was it was as easy as this. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! The extra hypothesis may have been a bit misleading.